# Cost of assigning a variable

Tags: c#, performance, linq, data-structures

```
var addr = (from s in context.Addresses
            where (s.u_address_id == new Guid(this.Id).ToString("B"))
             select s).Single();    
Address Addr = new Address(addr.u_address_id);
```

What is the cost of assigning a linq result to a variable instead of calling it directly in my usage as follow?

```
Address Addr = new Address(((from s in context.Addresses
                             where (s.u_address_id == new Guid(this.Id).ToString("B"))
                             select s).Single()).u_address_id);
```

Comment: approximately nothing.

Comment: in my opinion, you gain a bit of readability by separating out the query from the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None. They both do the same thing, but one names a local that would be hidden otherwise.

If you're that nuts for shaving every tiny cost away, why not do:

```
Address Addr = new Address((from s in context.Addresses
  where (s.u_address_id == new Guid(this.Id).ToString("B"))
  select s.u_address_id).Single());
```

Not getting all the fields could have an impact from absolutely minute, through pretty miniscule to enough that it would almost matter.

Even better:

```
string add_id = new Guid(this.Id).ToString("B");
if(context.Addresses.Count(s => s.u_address_id == add_id) != 1)
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
Address Addr = new Address(add_id);
```

(With some sources, `.Where(s => s.u_address_id == add_id).Take(2).Count()` is better, with others not).

Or if you can be confident such a item exists in the source, you can just do:

```
Address Addr = new Address(new Guid(this.Id).ToString("B"));
```

None of which are massive, but they're all much greater than the concern with giving a temporary a name. I think they get increasingly clear as to what they are actually doing as we go, too. I consider the last, the most readable.

Answer (score 4):

There is **no** cost in execution time or space consumption. In either case, a storage location is needed for a brief period of time. Some stack slot or register is briefly used to store a reference to the result of the `.Single()` call and pass it to the constructor. After that (assuming you don't use the variable again, which is heavily implied) it is not needed and can (will) be re-used.

More relevant factors could be readability, line length, coding standards, etc.

Comment: just to mention, he doesn't actually say "performance" cost.  "readability", for example, is actually a cost, as is variance from standard practices, and literally anything else you could possibly thing of.  Nothing has no costs, things just have small enough costs that they can be ignored, or the same costs as whatever you compare them to.

Comment: @Servy I did considered this, but it appears most people think of execution time or space needed when they say "cost" of some code. There's some kind of weird "OMG I need to know how many nanoseconds and bits this takes" mentality in some circles. Those insightful enough to consider these other costs explicitly spell out examples. I want to shut that train of thought down as efficiently as possible.

Comment: What most people think of and what they actually say are entirely different.  There are costs, that's a provable fact.  There are unlikely to be any performance costs, but there could potentially be minute performance costs.  Just because someone else may not have meant what they said doesn't mean you can or should mis-use the same words in your answer.  He didn't say "performance".  If you wish to just discuss performance then say so in your answer.  As is, it's technically wrong based entirely on your assumption of what the OP meant.

Comment: @Servy I will add that I'm assuming "cost = time/space cost". I would not consider the previous version *wrong* though unless my assumption is proven wrong (e.g. by OP clarifying "cost").

Comment: Well, you make the statement that "there is no cost".  You even bold no.  That statement is provably false.  There are costs.  Even if you change it to performance costs, that's still not provable fact (because of the JIT and details left up to the implementer, these things can vary based on your compiler, runtime, processor, etc.).

Comment: @Servy I already qualified "cost" a while ago, though not as explicitly. And yes, there is a slight chance that there is an implementation where there is a measurable difference. However, I claim my statement is correct at any scale above microbenchmarks (read: in any case that actually matters) using any non-toy JIT compiler. Even the most basic bytecode compiler+interpreter can eliminate any difference except not reusing the variable (which is likely just a word). And it only takes the most basic liveness analysis to optimize this. You are being pedantic here.

Comment: "absolutely no cost at all" and "no significant cost worth fretting over" are two different things.  I'm not saying it's an important performance consideration.  I'm saying your post doesn't accurately reflect what you know to be true, which is that the two are approximately the same, not exactly the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15982/discussion-between-delnan-and-servy)

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much in the way of costs.  You might (and yet might not) have a word or two of memory on the stack taken up for a bit longer in the first case, but that's pretty negligible in terms of costs.  Readability varies a bit between the two, and that's always a bit of a subjective case.  Here I'd say enough is going on that it's a bit more readable on two lines, and it could be a bit easier to debug when you aren't doing too much per line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that the variable is not optimized away by either the compiler or the JIT. Then you start worrying about storing 4 or 8 byte (32 or 64 bit) in RAM or a register.

Compare that to the rest of your code where your query is translated to SQL on the fly, sent over the network to a database server, parsed by the database server, executed by the database server, the result sent back over the network, the result materialized to an object that you can use.

Are you still worried about that 4 byte assignment? I'm not.

Comment: `s/registry/register/`? RE second paragraph: It may very well LINQ to objects. But even that means several method calls and memory allocations. Copying a word is still free compared to that.